# .NET MVC3 How do I get a link to a view to render the CSS?

Tags: .net, asp.net-mvc-3, model-view-controller

My stylesheets are properly referenced in the header, and render the CSS for the views properly when going through the controller, e.g:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="Content/style/ddlevelsmenu-base.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="Content/style/ddlevelsmenu-topbar.css">
```

But when I create a hyperlink in my menu like this:

```
<a href="home/index" class="blightblue"> <i class="icon-home"></i> Home</a>
```

It opens the page fine, but does not render the CSS.

I tried adding

```
@RenderSection("styles", false);
```

to my `Index` view, but it blew up.

I am using Visual Studio 2012 and MVC 3.

Comment: Are you able to see the page content without CSS ? do you have a Layout  set to null on this page ?

Comment: I can view the content of my index page either way, but when the Controller calls it, the CSS renders, when a hyperlink from within the Layout page calls it, the CSS does not render. I do not have the Layout set to Null on the index page. In fact there are no "settings" since it is a View; it only contains the ViewBag Title statement

Answer (score 0):

SOLUTION FOUND: Thanks to Jeff Widmer's Blog! He quotes Jeff King regarding Site-Relative Paths, which apparently is an issue with VS 2012 (I haven't checked later versions on this). Jeff King states that Visual Studio does not always know the final deployed location of your site (and in my case, I am in development, so that explains it!).

In any case, Jeff Widmer offers a solution that worked for me. I had to apply it to each of my stylesheet links (I have about 5 or 6!), but it works so it was worth it!

Here is Jeff's fix (this works for intellisense issues as well):

```
<link href="/content/default.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<% if (false) {%>
    <link href="../../content/default.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<% } %>
```

Works like a charm!

Here's a link to Jeff's blog: http://weblogs.asp.net/jeffwids/why-does-visual-studio-not-resolve-my-css-class-names

Comment: UPDATE
    <!-- HTML5 Support for IE -->
    <!--[if lt IE 11]>
    <script src="js/html5shim.js"></script>
    <![endif]-->